# What is required to hook up ASP.NET MVC to jQuery validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

What is required to use jQuery validation plug-in in ASP.NET MVC?  Do I just need to include `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in order to get it to work?

Comment: can people please comment on why they are down voting or flagging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you include the following two scripts -

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Further info can be found in this article - http://rachelappel.com/asp-net-mvc/how-data-annotations-for-asp-net-mvc-validation-work/

Answer (score 0):

To get jQuery Validation you just need to include jquery.validate.js
To have it be unobtrusive javascript then include jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

In order to get any validation all you have a few options:

```
1. Use DataAnnotations on your View Models
2. Use another library like FluentValidation which will use the jQuery validation.
3. Manually add the jquery validation calls.
```